# Logging query execution time from a MySQL Database in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an application coded in VB, and i was wondering if there is any way in which I am able to retrieve query execution time for a MySQL query.

I can see it in Workbench but I am looking to consign these into my application for query statistic reporting.

Does anyone have any material on this, I cannot seem to find what I want other than "Use Workbench for this"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to measure the execution time. Please note that you should start the watch *after* the connection is opened.

```
con.Open()

Dim watch As New Stopwatch()

watch.Start()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
watch.Stop()

con.Close()

Dim seconds As Double = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds()
```